# How would you write the code for this JSON in Android Studio?

Tags: json

What will be the code to get the data from my JSON which I have provided below. This is what I have written so far :

```
                JSONObject js = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = js.getJSONArray(Constants.Article);



            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }
    );

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

This is my JSON. I am confused as to how to resolve the json object right below my json Array "Article"

`{
"Article":[
{
"InvDepartmentId":"001000000000012",
"InvDepartmentName":"mens",
"InvCategoryId":"001000000000023",
"InvCategoryName":"adult",
"InvSubCategoryId":"001000000000021",
"InvSubCategoryName":"abc",
"ArticleId":"001000000000186",
"ArticleNo":"test22246",
"ArticleWSP":1100.00,
"CreatedOn":"2018-09-14T12:51:04",
"LastUpdate":"2018-09-14T12:51:30.823"
}`

Comment: Your JSON is not a valid JSON. Please fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this question. To get it better understanding it is always better to keep open to learning.
here are some tips to parse json in Java. google released the gson library which makes easier to parse json data.
first up all you JSON data is not correct. I modified the JSON and I have created POJO classes for the JSON data with gson annotation. finally I parsed the JSON using gson library.
Add following dependency to your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Modifie JSON file:

```
{
"Article":[
{
"InvDepartmentId":"001000000000012",
"InvDepartmentName":"mens",
"InvCategoryId":"001000000000023",
"InvCategoryName":"adult",
"InvSubCategoryId":"001000000000021",
"InvSubCategoryName":"abc",
"ArticleId":"001000000000186",
"ArticleNo":"test22246",
"ArticleWSP":1100.00,
"CreatedOn":"2018-09-14T12:51:04",
"LastUpdate":"2018-09-14T12:51:30.823"
}
]
}
```

I included all the POSO classes into the same class file. you can create as individual class file.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class JsonParse {
    public static String json = "{\r\n" + "\"Article\":[\r\n" + "{\r\n" + "\"InvDepartmentId\":\"001000000000012\",\r\n"
            + "\"InvDepartmentName\":\"mens\",\r\n" + "\"InvCategoryId\":\"001000000000023\",\r\n"
            + "\"InvCategoryName\":\"adult\",\r\n" + "\"InvSubCategoryId\":\"001000000000021\",\r\n"
            + "\"InvSubCategoryName\":\"abc\",\r\n" + "\"ArticleId\":\"001000000000186\",\r\n"
            + "\"ArticleNo\":\"test22246\",\r\n" + "\"ArticleWSP\":1100.00,\r\n"
            + "\"CreatedOn\":\"2018-09-14T12:51:04\",\r\n" + "\"LastUpdate\":\"2018-09-14T12:51:30.823\"\r\n" + "}\r\n"
            + "]\r\n" + "}";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Example articleList = gson.fromJson(json, Example.class);
        System.out.println(articleList.getArticle().get(0).getInvCategoryName());
    }

    public class Article {

        @SerializedName("InvDepartmentId")
        @Expose
        private String invDepartmentId;
        @SerializedName("InvDepartmentName")
        @Expose
        private String invDepartmentName;
        @SerializedName("InvCategoryId")
        @Expose
        private String invCategoryId;
        @SerializedName("InvCategoryName")
        @Expose
        private String invCategoryName;
        @SerializedName("InvSubCategoryId")
        @Expose
        private String invSubCategoryId;
        @SerializedName("InvSubCategoryName")
        @Expose
        private String invSubCategoryName;
        @SerializedName("ArticleId")
        @Expose
        private String articleId;
        @SerializedName("ArticleNo")
        @Expose
        private String articleNo;
        @SerializedName("ArticleWSP")
        @Expose
        private Double articleWSP;
        @SerializedName("CreatedOn")
        @Expose
        private String createdOn;
        @SerializedName("LastUpdate")
        @Expose
        private String lastUpdate;

        public String getInvDepartmentId() {
            return invDepartmentId;
        }

        public void setInvDepartmentId(String invDepartmentId) {
            this.invDepartmentId = invDepartmentId;
        }

        public String getInvDepartmentName() {
            return invDepartmentName;
        }

        public void setInvDepartmentName(String invDepartmentName) {
            this.invDepartmentName = invDepartmentName;
        }

        public String getInvCategoryId() {
            return invCategoryId;
        }

        public void setInvCategoryId(String invCategoryId) {
            this.invCategoryId = invCategoryId;
        }

        public String getInvCategoryName() {
            return invCategoryName;
        }

        public void setInvCategoryName(String invCategoryName) {
            this.invCategoryName = invCategoryName;
        }

        public String getInvSubCategoryId() {
            return invSubCategoryId;
        }

        public void setInvSubCategoryId(String invSubCategoryId) {
            this.invSubCategoryId = invSubCategoryId;
        }

        public String getInvSubCategoryName() {
            return invSubCategoryName;
        }

        public void setInvSubCategoryName(String invSubCategoryName) {
            this.invSubCategoryName = invSubCategoryName;
        }

        public String getArticleId() {
            return articleId;
        }

        public void setArticleId(String articleId) {
            this.articleId = articleId;
        }

        public String getArticleNo() {
            return articleNo;
        }

        public void setArticleNo(String articleNo) {
            this.articleNo = articleNo;
        }

        public Double getArticleWSP() {
            return articleWSP;
        }

        public void setArticleWSP(Double articleWSP) {
            this.articleWSP = articleWSP;
        }

        public String getCreatedOn() {
            return createdOn;
        }

        public void setCreatedOn(String createdOn) {
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }

        public String getLastUpdate() {
            return lastUpdate;
        }

        public void setLastUpdate(String lastUpdate) {
            this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        }

    }

    public class Example {

        @SerializedName("Article")
        @Expose
        private List<Article> article = null;

        public List<Article> getArticle() {
            return article;
        }

        public void setArticle(List<Article> article) {
            this.article = article;
        }

    }

}
```